# An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.10), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

- Os: Ubuntu 18.04
- ruby: 2.7
- rails: 6.*

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
> ```
>
> /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby -I
> /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
> ./siteconf20210329-30335-1ed7nme.rb extconf.rb
> --use-system-libraries checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
> probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the
> mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
> --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
> --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
> --ruby=/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)   --help
> --clean /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:471:in
> `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:597:in` block in
> try_compile'  from
> /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:544:in
> `with_werror'     from /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:597:in` try_compile'     from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'   from extconf.rb:162:in` block in add_cflags'   from
> /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:655:in
> `with_cflags'     from extconf.rb:161:in` add_cflags'     from
> extconf.rb:416:in `'
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
> which can be found here:
>
> /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nokogiri-1.10.10/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/nokogiri-1.10.10/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.10), and Bundler
> cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your mkmf.log file for more details.

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
```

**Solution**: brew unlink gcc

$ bundle install (will work fine)